# How to make AWS aurora Mysql into a writable instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-aurora

I am working on a project where we are creating a new region for resilience purpose.
As we create a new Region for the project, we also plan to create a Read replica of Aurora MySQL DB.
My question here has two parts

1. If the project in existing region goes down, how to make the read replica of Aurora MySQL in the other region as the new Master and writable?
   I searched through few videos and stackoverflow questions and I do understand how to make the RDS mysql as writable instance. but, I don't see how to make such a "read-only" parameter modification in Aurora MySQL!
2. How could I do this change with a Jenkins Job?

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the AWS CLI for this, specifically the:

> aws rds promote-read-replica-db-cluster

command which contrary to the name actually applies to Aurora as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/promote-read-replica-db-cluster.html) for the command:

> **Note**:
>   This action only applies to Aurora DB clusters.

You can find more information in the AWS documentation for Aurora, specifically the section on [Promoting a Read Replica to Be a DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.html).

2. Seems like you should be able to use the [Jenkins AWS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+AWS+Plugin) but there are many options.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashaman kingpin! Sorry for the late response though I saw your response couple of days ago itself. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help @Ram. Please don’t forget to accept the answer.

Comment: How do I accept? There is no accept button to be seen in the page!

Comment: @Ram Thanks!  It should be to the left of this post below the vote widget.  See here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Trying to understand this a little better.. is this specific to Global Databases? If I have one aurora cluster, with 2 instances inside it, is this API applicable to that ? Also, aurora instances are "writers" or "readers", so what does a replica cluster mean? Thanks!

Comment: No, this cli command is specific to read replicas, you can use remove-from-global-cluster to "promote" a cluster to a standalone cluster allowing writes.  Secondary clusters are read-only so they are "readers".